# Docusign users activation issue in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, docusignconnect

We have added new docusign users to salesforce portal and users have performed the activation from their end as well after clicking the link provided in activation email. But even after activation, it shows user status as "Pending" in salesforce and after that I went to docusign portal to verify user status and their its says user is "Active".

Can someone guide me on how to sync users between docusign and salesforce so that users can send the documents for signature?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on which version of the Salesforce package you're using. Users that have their individual logins access our system referencing their unique apiUserName. On the Salesforce side of things this is referred to as a DocuSign Username or a DsFsProUserName that is hidden by default. If you have an admin reveal this field on the User Settings page you can see which if any apiUserName is assigned to that individual.

If there isn't one, you'll want to copy the userId from the DocuSign side into the Salesforce field and save it.

If it's the *wrong* ID, you'll need to correct it.

If it's the *correct* ID I would recommend reaching out to customer support directly via support.docusign.com. Myself or someone from my team should be able to help you resolve this.

Regards,

Matt

Comment: Thanks @Matt for your quick response. I have installed latest version (version 3.5) of DocuSign application in Salesforce. 

With admin user which is used to connect Salesforce with DocuSign, I am able to send documents for signature and it is working seamlessly. Even I am getting completed documents back in Salesforce. I am only facing issue when I add a new user through DocuSign setup in Salesforce.

New user status is NOT getting updated in Salesforce from Pending to Active. I even verified User Id in both DocuSign and Salesforce and it is correct in both the portals.

Comment: I have even tried reinstallation of DocuSign app in salesforce and that also didn't work. 

In salesforce debug logs, I can see the script exception when newly added user tried to send document after accepting the DocuSign invitation -
 
`18:30:18.0 (297399884)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[EXTERNAL]|this|"common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Script-thrown exception"|0x23b71e3b
18:30:18.0 (297415290)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[EXTERNAL]|message|"You have not granted (75 more) ..." `